# Conflict between mysql_fetch_row and mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function in PHP that give me some values from DB

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sfide WHERE accepted = 0");

if($select){
    if(mysql_fetch_row($select) != 0){
        $sep = "~";
        $return = "";
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
            if($i > 0){
                $return = $return.",";
            };
            $return = $return.$row['id'].$sep.$row['from_'];
            $i += 1;
        }
        return $return;
    }else{
        return "NO";
    }
}else{
return "E, 000, SELECT, ".mysql_error();        
}
```

The problem is that if I do like in the code above it returns me nothing, instead, if I duplicate the select variable it works:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sfide WHERE accepted = 0");
$num_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sfide WHERE accepted = 0");
if($select){
    if(mysql_fetch_row($num_select) != 0){
        $sep = "~";
        $return = "";
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
            if($i > 0){
                $return = $return.",";
            };
            $return = $return.$row['id'].$sep.$row['from_'];
            $i += 1;
        }
        return $return;
    }else{
        return "NO";
    }
}else{
return "E, 000, SELECT, ".mysql_error();        
}
```

Why ?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` returns first row of the resultset and move internal pointer forward so `mysql_fetch_array` read the second row (or return false if it does not exists). You may take a look on [`mysql_num_rows`](http://uk1.php.net/mysql_num_rows) function to see how many rows are in the resultset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`mysql_fetch_row($select) != 0`

use

`mysql_num_rows($select) != 0`

that will return an `int` for you to compare.